# C# IKVM Toolkit not found Exception

Tags: exception, toolkit, ikvm

I am using IKVM 0.46.0.2 to wrap a java application into a dll in visual studio 2010 C# environment.

Code is, just create a java swing form using JFrame and pop up the some picture.

```
javax.swing.JFrame jf = new javax.swing.JFrame("Form title");
```

The following problem occurred.

```
Exception : java.awt.AWTError : Toolkit not found: ikvm.awt.NetToolkit, IKVM>AWT>WinForms, Version=0.46.0.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=13235d27fcbfff58

at : java.awt.Toolkit$2.run()
at : java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Object, AccessControlContext, CallerID)
at : java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(PrivilegedAction action, CallerID)
at : java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit()
at : java.awt.Window.getToolkit()
at : java.awt.Window.init(GraphicsConfiguration)
at : java.awt.window..ctor()
at : java.awt.Frame..ctor(String title)
at : javax.swing.JFrame..ctor(String title)
```

and I added reference file

```
IKVM.AWT.WinForms
IKVM.OpenJDK.Core
IKVM.OpenJDK.SwingAWT
IKVM.OpenJDK.Text
IKVM.OpenJDK.Util
IKVM.Runtime
```

How should I do to solve this problem?

thanks and sorry about my english

Answer (score 0):

The class ikvm.awt.NetToolkit is in the assembly IKVM.AWT.WinForms. You are sure the Visual Studio has copy the dll?

Seems a problem of classloading. How you have compiled your java application. See in the wiki for help with [classloading](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/ikvm/index.php?title=ClassLoader).